# Add breakpoints to databindings in VS2013

Tags: debugging, data-binding, visual-studio-2013

I have problem to add breakpoints in xaml code in VS2013, but in VS2012 is everything ok. Can anyone tell me what is different between VS2013 and VS 2012? What I have to set?

I have VS2013 Professional and I use .NET 4.5